# gas assembler: segmentation error while reading from keyboard (simple program)

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, gnu-assembler

i'm getting the segmentation error while trying running a simple assembly code.... basically i want to keep asking for an input form keybord until the return key is pressed, idk what is causing it since I'm new to gas assembly, could you kindly help me pls?

```
.section .data
    num:
       .int
.section .text
   .global _start

    _start: 
    leggi:
          movl $3, %eax
          movl $0, %ebx
          leal num, %ecx
          movl $1, %edx
          int $0x80
          movl $10,%edx
          cmp %edx,num
          jne leggi

          movl $1, %eax
          xorl %ebx,%ebx
          int $0x80
```

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that `.int` allowed you to specify zero or more expressions, and that it would create space for each of those expressions.

With *no* expressions, it may be allocating zero space, which will probably cause you problems. Possibly, with an empty `data` section, you'll be then writing into the first byte of the *next* section, which may well be the write-protected `text` section.

Have a look at the resulting output and see what it's doing. If that *is* the problem, you should be able to fix it with:

```
.int 0
```

However, you may also want to watch out for the fact that you're reading bytes but using int-sized data in your code. I'd probably be using `.byte` myself.

Comment: i used .byte 0 and it works now =) still the prgram keep asking for input even when return is pressed and won't exit the program

Comment: Sounds like jne leggi is simply doing an eternal loop (movl $10,%edx)
(cmp %edx,num) looks like you need to input $10

Comment: @Revex well that's a _different_ problem that should be asked in a different question. It looks like the SEGV has been solved with the addition of an argument to `.int/.byte`. If you ask a question in a _comment,_ you'll get a lot fewer eyes looking at it. However, I'd start by realising that `edx` is not a byte - you may need to load the _byte_ (from `num`) into a register and compare it with an immediate value `$10`).